# Проблема с массивом (js и php)

Tags: php, javascript, массивы, json

Строю график таким вот способом:

```
function addData(data) {
        /*for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            last30UsersDailyChartDataPoints.push({
                x: new Date(data[i][0]),
                y: data[i][2]
            });
        }*/
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        //last30UsersDailyChart.render();
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "statsapi.php",
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
            //addData(res);
            console.log(res);
        }
    });
```

И, собственно, `statsapi.php`:

```
$db->select(["count", "date"], "status", []);

while ($row = $db->getRow()) {
    echo json_encode(array_values($row));
}
```

Никак не пойму как правильно обработать этот JSON. Подскажите, пожалуйста

А, да, я получаю такой JSON:

```
["65","27.05"]["2","26.05"]["180","28.05"]["73","29.05"]["42","30.05"]["35","31.05"]["29","01.06"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Никак не пойму как правильно обработать этот JSON.

Cобрать данные, которые вам нужны, только после этого выводить на печать.

```
$db->select(["count", "date"], "status", []);
$res = []; // array()
while ($row = $db->getRow()) {
   $res[] = array_values($row); // Accumulate all values you need
}

echo json_encode($res); // Print result
```